# UWP App crash in release mode (faulting module: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll)

Tags: uwp, xamarin.uwp

My UWP app crashes directly after startup in release mode with following error in event log:

> Faulting application name: MyApp.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x6037ab09
> Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll, version: 10.0.17763.1790, time stamp: 0x05b3601b
> Exception code: 0xc000027b

When I install a debug build, everything's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging and Microsoft.Extensions.Options in Version 5.00. It turns out the native compiler ist stripping out some parts which are needed at runtime.

I found a description and a solution in this github issue: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/44697

So I had to add all the assemblies to Default.rd.xml located under Properties:

```
<Directives xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2013/01/metadata">
    <Application>
        <Assembly Name="*Application*" Dynamic="Required All" />
        
        <!-- Add your application specific runtime directives here. -->
        <Assembly Dynamic="Required All" Name="Microsoft.Extensions.Options"/>
        <Assembly Dynamic="Required All" Name="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging"/>
        <Assembly Dynamic="Required All" Name="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions"/>
        <Assembly Dynamic="Required All" Name="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting"/>
    </Application>
</Directives>
```