# Xamarin UWP Faulting module name: windows.ui.xaml.dll

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uwp

I have a strage bug on a UWP app.

Everything worked great until yesterday, also releasebuild on azure. Now I get the error `Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll` with the release build (on azure) as well as with the debug in visual studio.

This error occurs after I merged code changes from submodules that are not related to the UWP app into the develop branch. There are only small adjustments of method parameters, object structures and sync data with an api. If i Checkout the old commit it's work again.

Strangely I have this problem localy and with the Azure release build. 2 other developers have no problems locally on debug and release build.

What I have already tried:

- [Windows 10 UWP App crash at start (Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69476713/windows-10-uwp-app-crash-at-start-faulting-module-name-windows-ui-xaml-dll)
- [UWP App crash in release mode (faulting module: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66370711/uwp-app-crash-in-release-mode-faulting-module-windows-ui-xaml-dll)
- checking  packaging targetversion (we have all the same)
- check nugetversions (we have all the same)
- delete all bin and obj folders, cleanup and rebuild

I have no idea what else to try to fix the problem. Maybe someone facing the same or have an idea how to fix this?